How to let snakefmt skip a line?
How to tell snakefmt to ignore a line in a Snakefile?
This is my attempt to skip over a Jina template control statement:
{%if cookiecutter.include_r %}# fmt: skip

snakefmt.exceptions.InvalidPython: Black error:
Cannot parse: 26:1: {%if cookiecutter.include_r %}# fmt: skip

As snakefmt claims to "follows the design and specifications of Black", it may be worth trying black's way to ignore a line using # fmt: skip

Thank you @ManavalanGajapathy That's also what thought first, so I added # fmt: skip. That did not work.
